# Is it going to be an Android service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am new in Android Development. I want to create an application which would add a prefix to a calling number and this decision will depend on some parameters.

I want an user to be aware of it but doesn't have to do anything about it, meaning once the application is installed and an user wants to call, they'll just see that a prefix is going to be added to a number they are calling.

The question is not how to do adding a prefix to calling number (although, that's also what I want to know, but I have found an article about it), but rather:

1) is it going to be a service?

2) is it **possible** to change a **calling** number by adding a prefix to it and show a changed number to an user so that they don't have to do anything about it (like pressing "yes","no" to accept this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register for `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`

> > Broadcast Action: An outgoing call is about to be placed.
>
> The Intent will have the following extra value:
>
> EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER - the phone number originally intended to be
>   dialed. Once the broadcast is finished, the resultData is used as the
>   actual number to call. If null, no call will be placed.
>
> It is perfectly acceptable for multiple receivers to process the
>   outgoing call in turn: for example, a parental control application
>   might verify that the user is authorized to place the call at that
>   time, then a number-rewriting application might add an area code if
>   one was not specified.
>
> For consistency, any receiver whose purpose is to prohibit phone calls
>   should have a priority of 0, to ensure it will see the final phone
>   number to be dialed. Any receiver whose purpose is to rewrite phone
>   numbers to be called should have a positive priority. Negative
>   priorities are reserved for the system for this broadcast; using them
>   may cause problems.
>
> Any BroadcastReceiver receiving this Intent must not abort the
>   broadcast.
>
> Emergency calls cannot be intercepted using this mechanism, and other
>   calls cannot be modified to call emergency numbers using this
>   mechanism.
>
> Some apps (such as VoIP apps) may want to redirect the outgoing call
>   to use their own service instead. Those apps should first prevent the
>   call from being placed by setting resultData to null and then start
>   their own app to make the call.
>
> You must hold the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission to receive this
>   Intent.
>
> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"

Comment: and do I have to build it as a service?

Comment: no as long as your process doesn't take too long you can use a broadcastreceiver

Comment: No you just append the prefix in the broadcast receiver.